# NASM Assembly Language Compile and run on Windows

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

I have an assignment in an Assembly Language Class, but the teacher and all the lab computers run on Mac and/or Linux. I unfortunately use exclusively Windows devices and have no clue how to get my code to compile and run. I have read through several examples on the internet and on here, and every single one of them does something unique and different (even all specifically for Windows). The assignment is as follows:

You are to read in two integer numbers, A and B.  You are to use those two integers to compute the following expression: answer = A * B + ( A + B ) / ( A - B ).  You should produce an error message should A-B be zero, as that will cause the division to fail.

What is the best IDE to write in? Is notepad++ fine? I downloaded NASM but dont know where to put the extracted files. I been going through so many different programs, files, and settings trying to figure out why this can't just have a simple solution.

Comment: Installation problems aside, be advised that if you write code for windows that won't work on linux so depending on the assignment it might not be accepted.

Comment: Have to agree with @Jester on this. The way in which you display things on the screen, get input etc. are quite different between Windows and Linux and is even different for the Mac. It is unclear from your question exactly what platform your assignment has to compile and run on, or whether you have the choice.